# (Again) eliminate curly brackets from PopupMenu?

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

How can I display the items in a `PopupMenu` , which is fed by a list, without the curly brackets? The sample code is:

```
list = {{1, a, x}, {2, b, y}, {3, c, z}}
Manipulate[Grid[{p}, Frame -> All], {p, list, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

The result currently looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way.

```
items = # -> Row[#, " "] & /@ {{1, a, x}, {2, b, y}, {3, c, z}}
Manipulate[
 Grid[{p}, Frame -> All],
 {{p, items[[1, 1]]}, items, PopupMenu}]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: ok, and would it be possible to keep the comas between the elements of each item in `PopupMenu`?

Comment: Sure, just use `items = # -> Row[#, ", "] & /@ {{1, a, x}, {2, b, y}, {3, c, z}}` -- the 2nd argument of `Row` sets what goes between the items in the 1st argument. If you don't like the space after the comma, just delete the space from ", ".

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a custom controller function to your Manipulate that provides a `PopupMenu` with appropriate custom labels:

```
list = {{1, a, x}, {2, b, y}, {3, c, z}}

Manipulate[
 Grid[{p}, Frame -> All],
 {
  (*Initial value for the control*)
  {p, list[[1]]},
  (*Custom controller function*)
  Function[value, PopupMenu[value, (# -> Row[#, " "] &) /@ list]]
  }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]